# DB2: NOT EXISTS and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, left-join

May I know why the following 2 queries return different values. I want exact result as the first one using LEFT OUTER JOIN. Please help.

```
select count(a.ADDRESS_ID) from ADDRESS a where a.MEMBER_ID >= 50000000 and a.MEMBER_ID <= 999999999 and a.STATUS='T' and a.LASTCREATE < (current timestamp - 42 days) 
    and not exists (select 1 from ORDERS o where o.ADDRESS_ID = a.ADDRESS_ID) 
    and not exists (select 1 from ORDERITEMS oi where oi.ADDRESS_ID = a.ADDRESS_ID or oi.ALLOCADDRESS_ID = a.ADDRESS_ID) 
    and not exists (select 1 from HD_MEMBER_SUBSCR ms where ms.ADDRESS_ID = a.ADDRESS_ID) 
fetch first 800000 rows only for read only with ur;


select count(ADDRESS_ID) FROM ADDRESS
WHERE MEMBER_ID >= 50000000 
  AND MEMBER_ID < 999999999
  AND STATUS = 'T'
  AND LASTCREATE < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 42 DAYS)
  AND ADDRESS_ID IN (
    SELECT a.ADDRESS_ID
    FROM ADDRESS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS o
      ON o.ADDRESS_ID = a.ADDRESS_ID AND o.ADDRESS_ID IS NULL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERITEMS oi
      ON oi.ADDRESS_ID = a.ADDRESS_ID AND oi.ADDRESS_ID IS NULL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERITEMS oi2
      ON oi2.ALLOCADDRESS_ID = a.ADDRESS_ID AND oi2.ALLOCADDRESS_ID IS NULL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN HD_MEMBER_SUBSCR hms
      ON hms.ADDRESS_ID = a.ADDRESS_ID AND hms.ADDRESS_ID IS NULL
  FETCH FIRST 800000 ROWS ONLY
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two reasons:

(1) You are fetching a limited number of rows with no `order by` clause.  The rows can be returned in any order and the first 800,000 may not be the same for the two queries.

(2) One or more of the joins has multiple matches.  This would result in duplicates in the result set.

Comment: I want exact ditto of the first query using LEFT OUTER JOIN. Can you help?

Comment: @user3175639 . . . Why?  It is a rather complicated query to structure that way and you already have it working.

Answer (score 0):

The join will work when you place the "AND o.ADDRESS_ID IS NULL" in the where clause of the SQL statement instead of on the join itself. Example

```
select a.userid, b.userid from USER a
left join ROUTING b on a.userid = b.userid 
where a.userid = '365' and b.userid IS NULL
with ur
```